# Native script persian calendar

Tags: nativescript

According to articles if i want to create a project that share between mobile and web too i can use Native script, i know angular has persian calendar but i did not find any for Native Script. I should use Native script  plugin for this purpose  so can not  use the angular calendar in NS.

The first question is : is it true that i can not use angular calendar in native script and we can use just its plugin?

Second: if question 1 is true so any body know any calendar plugin for native script?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use Angular calendar plugin in {N}, obviously the web version would have been built with HTML DOM which is not supported in {N}.

Here we use Native UI elements of respective platform, so you could try the [nativescript-ui-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ui-calendar) plugin and try setting `locale` to **fa-IR** I'm not sure whether it gives the expected results fully but it's one of the best option available.

Otherwise you should find a Persian Calendar for iOS / Android, a quick search shows [PersianCalendar for iOS](https://github.com/farhad1985/PersianCalendar) / [Persian Calendar View for Android](https://github.com/Roojin/persian-calendar-view), you may install those dependencies in POD / Gradle and use it in your Project.

Comment: is it  possible to use native component (for Android or iOS) in {NS}:?